# ProcessRequest Vs AuthenticateRequest

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a question from the .net:-

You're creating a new authentication system that uses an HTTP header value. The existing authentication system must continue to operate normally. You need to implement the custom authentication. What should you do?

A. Create an HttpHandler to check for a valid HTTP header value in the ProcessRequest method.

B. Create an HttpModule and check for a valid HTTP header value in the AuthenticateRequest event.

My research:
ProcessRequest - This method is actually the heart of all http handlers. This method is called to process http request.

AuthenticateRequest - This event is raised when ASP.Net runtime is ready to authenticate the identity of the user

Please advise which answer is correct.

Thank you.

Regards,

Akane

Answer (score 2):

Answer is B. Create an HTTPModule and check for a valid HTTP header value in the AuthenticateRequest event.

HTTP module will basically provide a custom authentication service. It will receive authentication credentials in HTTP request and will determine whether those credentials are valid.

please refer the below link for more info

http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_asp/article.php/c19389/HTTP-Handlers-and-HTTP-Modules-in-ASPNET.htm